# $ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_{ji})^{n}} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n} ( x_{ji}) \right)$

Tags: inequality, summation

$$\forall x_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{+} , | , i \in {1, 2, 3, \ldots, m}, , j \in {1, 2, 3, \ldots, n} \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_{ji})^{n}} \geq 
\sum_{i=1}^{m} \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n} ( x_{ji}) \right)$$

[image: photo of the question]
I am sharing my attempt as answer

Answer (score 1):

The statement as written is false. Here's a counterexample:

Consider for $m = n = 2$ the values

$$x_{ji} = 2(j-1) + i.$$

So

$$x_{11} = 1,\qquad x_{12} = 2, \qquad x_{21} = 3,\qquad x_{22} = 4.$$

Then

$$LHS = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} + \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = \sqrt{5} + 5 < 3 + 8 = (1\cdot 3) + (2\cdot 4) = RHS.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
a_{1}^3 + a_{2}^3 + a_{3}^3 &\geq 3(a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}) \\
a_1 &= x_j \sqrt[3]{x_{1}^3 + x_{2}^3 + \ldots + x_{n}^3} \\
a_2 &= y_j \sqrt[3]{y_{1}^3 + y_{2}^3 + \ldots + y_{3}^3}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a_3 &= z_j \sqrt[3]{z_1^3 + z_2^3 + \ldots + z_n^3} \quad \text{for } j = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{3x_1y_1z_1}{\sqrt[3]{x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \ldots + x_n^3} \sqrt[3]{y_1^3 + y_2^3 + \ldots + y_3^3} \sqrt[3]{z_1^3 + z_2^3 + \ldots + z_n^3}}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\geq \frac{x_1^3}{x_1^3 + x_{2}^3 + \ldots + x_n^3} + \frac{y_1^3}{y_1^3 + y_2^3 + \ldots + y_3^3} \\
& + \frac{z_1^3}{z_1^3 + z_2^3 + \ldots + z_n^3}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{3x_2y_2z_2}{\sqrt[3]{x_{1}^3 + x_{2}^3 + \ldots + x_n^3} \sqrt[3]{y_{1}^3 + y_{2}^3 + \ldots + y_{3}^3} \sqrt[3]{z_{1}^3 + z_{2}^3 + \ldots + z_n^3}}
\end{align}

**Am I on right way and this method is super lengthy and complex so any other method to prove this inequality**